# Will a Python generator be garbage collected if it will not be used any more but hasn't reached StopIteration yet?

Tags: python, garbage-collection, generator, coroutine

When a generator is not used any more, it should be garbage collected, right? I tried the following code but I am not sure which part I was wrong.

```
import weakref
import gc

def countdown(n):
    while n:
        yield n
        n-=1

cd = countdown(10)
cdw = weakref.ref(cd)()
print cd.next()
gc.collect()
print cd.next()
gc.collect()
print cdw.next()
```

On the second last line, I called garbage collector and since there is no call to `cd` any more. `gc` should free `cd` right. But when I call `cdw.next()`, it is still printing 8. I tried a few more `cdw.next()`, it could successfully print all the rest until StopIteration.

I tried this because I wanted to understand how generator and coroutine work. On slide 28 of David Beazley's PyCon presentation "A Curious Course on Coroutines and Concurrency", he said that a coroutine might run indefinitely and we should use `.close()` to shut it down. Then he said that garbage collector will call `.close()`. In my understanding, once we called `.close()` ourselves, `gc` will call `.close()` again. Will `gc` receive a warning that it can't call `.close()` on an already closed coroutine?

Thanks for any inputs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Due to the dynamic nature of python, the reference to `cd` isn't freed until you reach the end of the current routine because (at least) the Cpython implementation of python doesn't "read ahead".  (If you don't know what python implementation you're using, it's almost certainly "Cpython").  There are a number of subtleties that would make that virtually impossible for the interpreter to determine whether an object should be free if it still exists in the current namespace in the general case (e.g. you can still reach it by a call to `locals()`).

In some less general cases, other python implementations may be able to free an object before the end of the current stack frame, but Cpython doesn't bother.

Try this code instead which demonstrates that the generator is free to be cleaned up in Cpython:

```
import weakref
def countdown(n):
    while n:
        yield n
        n-=1

def func():
    a = countdown(10)
    b = weakref.ref(a)
    print next(a)
    print next(a)
    return b

c = func()
print c()
```

Objects (including generators) are garbage collected when their reference count reaches 0 (in Cpython -- Other implementations may work differently).  In Cpython, reference counts are only decremented when you see a `del` statement, or when an object goes out of scope because the current namespace changes.

The important thing is that once there are no more references to an object, it is free to be cleaned up by the garbage collector.  The details of how the implementation determines that there are no more references are left to the implementers of the particular python distribution you're using.

Comment: Actually, I think PyPy could do that if `func` was called in a loop. It may not even allocate the generator at all. (I doubt it currently does that if generators are currently as unoptimized as fijal says, but it already does this with many other objects.) The problem isn't that Python is dynamic, the problem is that CPython doesn't even attempt to rule out dynamicness even if it could. Of course, the refcount explanation at the end is also CPython-specific. The `c()` in your example may very well print something in PyPy, Jython or IronPython.

Comment: @delnan -- You're correct about the reference counting bit.  However, how does PyPy handle the case where you do something like `locals()[other_str[::2][::-1]]` when it doesn't know ahead of the time what `other_str` (and consequently it's slices) are going to be?  Granted, this is an insane case, but the python interpreter should allow it.  I suppose it could look ahead for `locals`, `vars` and `globals` and disable immediate garbage collection only if they're not present or something ... but I think that we could say that the dynamic nature prevents immediate collection in *some* cases ...

Comment: It handles that the same way it handles all other dynamic weirdness (strange types popping up, replacing methods or classes or modules, fiddling with `__dict__`, etc): It bails out of the optimized code, and does the inefficient thing (sometimes even more convulted than what CPython does), starting with what it would have already done (e.g. allocating intermediate objects) if it hadn't optimized at all. This is tracing JIT compiler 101. How did you think PyPy managed to optimize *anything*?

Comment: And yes, practically there will always be cases where an optimization is valid but wasn't detected to be valid (finding *the optimal* program is simply not worth the exponential effort), but that's always the case for all optimizations for almost all languages and a whole lot better than "it's just not possible at all". It's probably slightly more common with very dynamic languages, but many many optimizations are still feasible.

Answer (score 8):

In your example, the generator won't get garbage collected until the end of the script. Python doesn't know if you're going to be using `cd` again, so it can't throw it away. To put it precisely, there's still a *reference* to your generator in the *global namespace*.

A generator will get GCed when its *reference count* drops to zero, just like any other object. Even if the generator is not exhausted.

This can happen under lots of normal circumstances - if it's in a local name that falls out of scope, if it's `del`ed, if its owner gets GCed. But if any live objects (including namespaces) hold strong references to it, it won't get GCed.

Answer (score 4):

The Python garbage collector isn't quite that smart. Even though you don't refer to `cd` any more after that line, the reference is still live in local variables, so it can't be collected. (In fact, it's possible that some code you're using might dig around in your local variables and resurrect it. Unlikely, but possible. So Python can't make any assumptions.)

If you want to make the garbage collector actually do something here, try adding:

```
del cd
```

This will remove the local variable, allowing the object to be collected.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers have explained that `gc.collect()` won't garbage collect anything that still has references to it. There is still a live reference `cd` to the generator, so it will not be gc'ed until `cd` is deleted.

However in addition, the OP is creating a SECOND strong reference to the object using this line, which calls the weak reference object:

```
cdw = weakref.ref(cd)()
```

So if one were to do `del cd` and call `gc.collect()`, the generator would *still* not be gc'ed because `cdw` is also a reference.

To obtain an actual weak reference, do not call the `weakref.ref` object. Simply do this:

```
cdw = weakref.ref(cd)
```

Now when `cd` is deleted and garbage collected, the reference count will be zero and calling the weak reference will result in `None`, as expected.