# Alpha-beta pruning with python generators

Tags: python

I want to analyze a game using minimax with alpha-beta pruning in python.  The pseudocode will be something like

```
def alphabeta(node, depth, alpha, beta, isMaxNode):
   blah blah
   for each child of node
      blah blah
```

In this particular game, calculating the children of a node is rather complicated, so I'd like to define a generator

```
def children(node):
    blah blah
    yield child
```

and then have

```
for child in children(node)
```

as the implementation of the `for` loop above.

I'm worried about what happens when an alpha-beta cutoff occurs, so that there is a break in the `for each child` loop, and we never get to the end of the generator.  What happens to the closure?  Is it garbage collected, or will I have a bunch of unresolved closures chewing up the memory?

It seems like I should know the answer to this.  I would think that the closure goes out of scope when the break occurs, and becomes eligible for garbage-collection, but I'm not sure.

This is different from [Will a Python generator be garbage collected if it will not be used any more but hasn't reached StopIteration yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490127/will-a-python-generator-be-garbage-collected-if-it-will-not-be-used-any-more-but)

In that question, the generator has not gone out of scope, and the compiler would have to read the code and determine that the generator isn't called again.  It seems to me, however, that in the case I pose in this question, the generator should be out of scope and eligible for garbage collection once a `break` occurs in the `for` loop.  Is that right?

**EDIT**

Looking at the code again, I realize that once an alpha-beta cutoff, the function `alphabeta` not only breaks out of the `for` loop, it returns.  That makes it seem even more likely that generator object would be garbage-collected, but I don't know anything about the details of the cPython implementation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will a Python generator be garbage collected if it will not be used any more but hasn't reached StopIteration yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490127/will-a-python-generator-be-garbage-collected-if-it-will-not-be-used-any-more-but)

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks.  Please see how I've edited my question.

Comment: Your question seems a bit hazy, mostly because you dont have an example.  Once an item is Yielded, it cant be refetched.  The only things existing in memory are the function and the current iteration.  If you ever want to maintain data after it is yielded, you need to turn the result into a list instead of iterating on a yield. You need to store it in the Forloop somehow.  its one and done when doing a forloop with a yield'ing function.

Comment: @Fallenreaper I don't want to refetch anything.  What I'm talking about is what you are calling the current iteration.  When is that garbage collected?

Comment: it is generally freed immediately or when the language itself enacts it.  Thats the thing that is so good with generators, is that it keeps the payload really small.  I use them as much as possible if i dont need to have ALL items in memory at once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15490127/will-a-python-generator-be-garbage-collected-if-it-will-not-be-used-any-more-but